# I'm running into dependency issues trying to run an unfamilliar gradle build that I believe worked on an older version of gradle

Tags: gradle

I've been put into the unfortunate situation where I need to deploy a gradle build on a time crunch when I have never worked with it before. I believe this worked previously but on an older version of gradle that I am unable to roll back to.

I'm running Gradle 7.1 and am receiving this error message:

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.slf4j,
> name=slf4j-api, version=1.7.21}] on object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

This is the build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    ext.springVersion="4.2.0.RELEASE"
    ext.slf4jVersion="1.7.10"
    ext.springDataVersion = "1.8.0.RELEASE"
    ext.hibernateVersion = "4.3.9.Final"
    ext.springSecurityVersion = "4.2.0.RELEASE"
    ext.springDataMongoDBVersion = "1.7.0.RELEASE"
    ext.mysqlConnectorVersion = "5.1.13"
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'    
    apply plugin : 'eclipse-wtp'
    
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    
    group = 'com.aet.accel'
    version = '1.0.0'
    
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{url "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"}
        maven{url "https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        // logging
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
        compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.5'
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5"
    }
}
```

Any sort of assistance is very much appreciated, as I am very out of my depth on this one. Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

compile has been deprecated, so for libraries use api or implementation